# yshift for arrow labels in tikz-cd, without also shifting arrow

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-cd

The syntax for arrows in [tikz-cd](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-cd/tikz-cd-doc.pdf) is `\arrow[options]`. Arrows can either be positioned relatively (e.g. `\arrow[r, "\phi"]`) or absolutely (`\arrow[from=1-1, to=1-2, "\phi"]`). I want to shift the label of an arrow vertically, without also shifting the arrow itself. There is a `yshift` syntax in tikz-cd, but this shifts the arrow along with the label.

I can revert to tikz and use a notation like the following `\arrow{r}[yshift=1ex]{\phi}`, but this is inconvenient, as it doesn't compose with the other tikz-cd syntax. In addition, I'm not sure how to conveniently use absolute positioning with tikz-cd's grid using tikz directly.

Is there a convenient way to achieve this, or is this a shortcoming with tikz-cd?

---

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow[from=1-1, to=1-2, "\phi"] & B
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image: A \xto{\phi} B]

I want to shift `\phi` up without moving the arrow itself.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! Please give a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). Currently we have to guess what you are using and this makes it really hard to help you. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, have a minimal preamble  and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. The code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. it is much easier to help you if you give us something to start from.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As usual in the quotes syntax, you can just add keys after `"\phi"`, e.g.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow[from=1-1, to=1-2, "\phi" {yshift=1pt}] & B
\end{tikzcd}

\begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow[from=1-1, to=1-2, "\phi" {yshift=5pt}] & B
\end{tikzcd}

\begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow[from=1-1, to=1-2, "\phi" {yshift=3pt,red}] & B
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect — can't believe I didn't realise this was possible! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**

In the first version of answer i misread of question. Now is (hopefully) correct:

- global setting (for all arrows in diagram):

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzcd}[labels={inner sep=1ex}]
A \ar[r, "\phi"] & B
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

- local setting and use `yshift` option:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzcd}
A \ar[r, "\phi", every label/.style={red,yshift=2ex}] & B
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

- local setting with defining arrow's label style, for example:

```
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzcd}[SL/.style = {every label/.style={red,yshift=#1}}]
A \ar[r, "\phi", SL=2ex] & B
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The second solution is sufficient for my use case, thanks! However, I've accepted the other answer simply because it's a little more elegant.